# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried all CDN but always get error. Please suggest correct CDN

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#divLookUp").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      minWidth: 600,
      show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.form/4.2.1/jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: Did you link jqueryui.js?

Comment: When posting code make sure that everything is visible in the preview. Your whole script tags have not been visible.

Comment: Why do you include multiple jQuery and jQuer-ui versions?

Comment: Do you test your code in the context of `https` or `http`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the your html file :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>`

Comment: @SANJOG please use this path http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Also try $   and   jQuery ,  sometimes it gots some conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

On first line you're just importing the jQueryUI css and not the JavaScript library. You need to add the the jQueryUI js dependency and the jQuery js dependency (please note the **https** source).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<button id="openDialogBtn">Click to open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="I'm the dialog title" hidden="hidden">I'm the dialog body</div>

<script>
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth: 600,
    show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
    }
});

$("#openDialogBtn").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation for `jQuery(...).dialog is not a function` with the given code is that the browser blocked loading `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js`, this might be because you tested the given code one a `https` website, or probably because you have enabled a script blocker.

If your tested your code on `https` then the loading of all scripts that start with `http:` are blocked. If you change your code loading to this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#divLookUp").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      minWidth: 600,
      show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 200
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.form/4.2.1/jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

The error would not be there anymore. But you still have the problem that you load multiple jQuery and jQuery UI versions.

If the problem still persist, then the your browser or some thing else blocks the loading of jquery ui.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following

```
        var box = $("#wait").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            //height: 150,
            //weight: 50,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        }).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#wait").dialog('open');
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $("#wait").dialog('close');    
        });
```

I used below code. It worked.

$(function () {

```
        var box = $("#wait").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            //height: 150,
            //weight: 50,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        }).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $('#wait').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;  
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $('#wait').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Try this code, tested on my setup. Working properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="bilal" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>

<script>

  $( function() {
    $( "#bilal" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
  minWidth: 600,
  show: {
    effect: "clip",
    duration: 200
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "clip",
    duration: 200
  }
    });
  } );

</script>
```

Try this code, tested on my setup. Working fine. Thanks

Comment: what is difference